# Can long, untwisted wires damage a relay?

Tags: relay, cables

I have two long, straight wires of about 300 meters that are being used to activate a 120VAC@1A relay.

Could this damage the relay due to them being long and untwisted?

Comment: `120 VAC 1 Amp` coil rating or switch rating? Anyway, the wires better not exceed 9% of the coil resistance (drive voltage = rated coil voltage).

Comment: Lightning might be a consideration. Significant energy can be induced into those long wires. Something like a varistor could mitigate such an issue.

Comment: Re *"wheather"*: It is probably *"[whether](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whether#Conjunction)"* (not related to precipitation); though it isn't needed if transformed into an actual question.

Answer (score 7):

I presume that the question is "will such a long wire will damage the relay". (Also that English is not the OP's native language, so OK.)

There is no reason that a long wire, twisted or not, would damage a relay. However if the resistance of the wire is too high, the relay might fail to activate due to too much voltage drop on the wire. You can and should calculate this. You need to know the resistance of the wire and relay, and the minimum turn on voltage for the relay. For example:

[7/0.2 wire](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/313271.pdf) has a resistance of 93R/km. 300m of wire has 0.6km round trip, so 0.6 x 93 = 56R

Now take a fairly standard 12V relay like [this one](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2340399.pdf). There are two parameters we are interested in - coil resistance and "must turn on" voltage.

Coil resistance is 1315R for the 12V version, and "must turn on" voltage is 80% of nominal (9.6V for a 12V relay). To work it through, let's say we supply 12V:

total resistance of the series circuit = 1315 + 56 = 1371R

And for 12V supply, the relay will get (1315/1371) x 12 = 11.5V

So no problem, 11.5V is well over the 9.6V minimum.

We can also calculate the maximum cable run that will work with this relay. If cable resistance is 25% of the relay resistance, we will drop the source voltage by 80%. In this case it would be 329R, that's 3.5km of 7/0.2, a round-trip distance of 1.7km.

Note that this assumes that the relay has a dedicated pair of wires - if multiple relays share a common return wire (for instance), things become slightly more complex.

Comment: You may also want to consider that a long-untwisted wire might add many uH of inductance in series with the relay coil.  There is always inductive kickback when switching a relay on/off.  If using external kickback protection, then one would need to account for the extra inductance.  If the protection is built into the relay, then at some point adding enough extra inductance will cause it to fail.  But practically speaking things like wire resistance might cause other problems first.

Comment: But that inductive kick won't, usually, damage the relay.   It may damage the driving device.  Note that the relay coil itself will cause an inductive kick if unsupressed.

Comment: yes, if driving a relay from a transistor, a protection device (usually a diode) is required, near the transistor. Yes there is extra inductance and capacitance from the line (twisted or not), but a relay coil is not affected by that.